# Efficient Way of Mapping data from Map to DTO/VO Object

Tags: java

I have a Map with values and i want to map this values to a DTO

Rather than using if else conditions and mapping to DTO Object , is there any better way of doing so

This is my code

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashMap<String , Object> hashMap = new HashMap<String , Object>();
        hashMap.put("empName", "Pavan");
        hashMap.put("deptNO", "12");
        hashMap.put("country", "IND");
        hashMap.put("age", "34");
        
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Set<String> keys = hashMap.keySet();
        for(String key: keys){
            Employee emp = new Employee();
            if(key.equals("empName"))
            emp.setName(hashMap.get("empName"))
        }
    }
}

public class Employee {
    
    private String empName ;
    private String deptNO ;
    private String country ;
    private String age ;
    
    // setters and getters
}
```

I know the tradational way of doing as

```
for(String key: keys){
  Employee emp = new Employee();
  if(key.equals("empName"))
     emp.setName(hashMap.get("empName"))
}
```

Is there any better way of doing this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the BeanUtils.populate to copy your HashMap keys to a bean, here's an example:

```
import org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtils;

import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Test {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException {

        HashMap<String , Object> hashMap = new HashMap<String , Object>();
        hashMap.put("empName", "Pavan");
        hashMap.put("deptNO", "12");
        hashMap.put("country", "IND");
        hashMap.put("age", "34");
        EmployeeDTO employeeDTO = new EmployeeDTO();
        BeanUtils.populate(employeeDTO,hashMap);
        System.out.println(employeeDTO);

    }

}
```

**Output**

```
EmployeeDTO{empName='Pavan', deptNO='12', country='IND', age='34'}
```

Read more here:

- https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanUtils.html
- https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java_beanutils/data_type_conversions_beanutils_and_convertutils.htm

Comment: OP had asked mapping from `HashMap` to bean. How does `BeanUtils.copyProperties(user, userDTO);` solve that problem ?

Comment: Good point, @Pankaj!

I have corrected my answer so that it uses correct BeanUtils method and updated the provided example.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a parameterized constructor for Employee class

```
public class Employee {
    
    private String empName;
    private String deptNO;
    private String country;
    private String age;
    
    Employee(String empName, String deptNO, String country, String age){
       this.empName = empName;
       this.deptNO = deptNO;
       this.country = country;
       this.age = age;
    }
}
```

and you can create Employee object from map.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashMap<String , Object> hashMap = new HashMap<String , Object>();
        hashMap.put("empName", "Pavan");
        hashMap.put("deptNO", "12");
        hashMap.put("country", "IND");
        hashMap.put("age", "34");
        
        Employee emp = new Employee(hashMap.get("empName"), hashMap.get("deptNO"), hashMap.get("country"), hashMap.get("age"));
    }
}
```

EDIT: If you have many fields in map, you can use hashmap in Employee class to get the existing properties.

```
public class Employee {
    private HashMap<String, Object> hashMap;
    
    Employee(HashMap<String, Object> hashMap){
       this.hashMap = hashMap;
    }

    public Object getProperty(String propertyName){
       return hashMap.get(propertyName);
    }
}
```

Comment: the map consists of 15 fields ., and any other plan ?

Comment: @Pavan How are you creating this map? Is it created in your code?

Comment: comes from api call , from 3rd party

Comment: Then you can directly create POJO from api response or you can hold this map in Employee class and create a generic `getProperty(String propertyName)` which return the value of `propertyName` from map if value exists.

Answer (score 0):

Approach using [MapStruct](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/) -

Defined an interface `EmployeeMapper`

```
@Mapper
public interface EmployeeMapper {

  EmployeeMapper MAPPER = Mappers.getMapper(EmployeeMapper.class);

  @Mapping(expression = "java(parameters.get(\"empName\"))", target = "empName")
  @Mapping(expression = "java(parameters.get(\"deptNO\"))", target = "deptNO")
  @Mapping(expression = "java(parameters.get(\"country\"))", target = "country")
  @Mapping(expression = "java(parameters.get(\"age\"))", target = "age")
  Employee map(final Map<String, String> parameters);
}
```

and in your code call as -

```
Employee employee = EmployeeMapper.MAPPER.map(hashMap);
```

This is not as concise as you want but it does the work. Another approach is to use `Qualifier`, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44391235/2478531). `Qualifier` approach is verbose and it doesn't solve your problem entirely as you still need to define mapping for each field.

`MapStruct` currently doesn't have full support for conversion from `Map` and there is a [feature request](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/pull/1744) and [PR](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/pull/1744) pending for long.